# Removing Comment and Doctype from BS4 parser when running throug soup()

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove the Comments and Doctype of a BS4 instance by doing the following:

```
for elt in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, (Doctype, Comment))):
    elt.extract()
```

But right after, I loop over all the items, one by one, to run some custom processing.

I feel like it's doing the loop twice, which is not great in terms of performances.

But when I try to do :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(message, features='html.parser')
for tag in soup():
    if isinstance(tag, (Comment, Doctype)):
        tag.extract()
```

It doesn't work because `tag` is always a `bs4.element.Tag`.

Is there way to loop to all elements via `for tag in soup()`, and removing the comments and the doctype?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding your concern with efficiency. You say that the first snippet is working, but since after it, you have to loop over again, this might end in a not-efficient solution.

Let's put on the algorithm hat on. Iterate over a list is O(n), in your case n is equal to the soup objects. Then you have to re-iterate over the objects (minus the removed tags) therefore 2*O(n) => O(n) as the worst case scenario.

The solution your propose is to remove the tags within a loop. But then, unless you are performing the filter within that loop, you will still end up with the same 2 loops. Resulting in a **not** efficient way, since you are basically re-implementing the tag removal.

#######

But to reply **specifically** to your question as "How do I navigate through soup tags and objects?" Then my suggestion would be to traverse the soup object with: `descendants`, `children`, `next`, and `previous`. Here the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Why do you assume that I do a second loop within the loop inside the second option? It should technically not do a second loop: since I'm iterating, inside the loop, I'm testing if the current element matches the type I'm looking for, so I don't do a second loop inside it ?